# Access an object in an NSArray using a key path

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsarray, key-value-coding

I've read through the KVC docs on Apple and it talks in depth about making your indexed collections accessible through key value coding, but I can't find any examples of a key path being used to access an arbitrary element within the array.

If my Blob class has an NSArray *widgets, I'd like to be able to get the widget at index 4 by doing something like:

```
[myBlob valueForKeyPath:@"widgets[4]"]
```

Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

myBlob answers to 'valueForKey:' and widgets being an NSArray answers to 'objectAtIndex:'.
So '[[myBlob valueForKey:@"widgets"] objectAtIndex:4]' should do the trick.